# .NET Web application fails to read currently running Services

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

I have some code that tries to get a list of currently running services and find a specific one off of that list.

```
using (ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_Service"))
            {
                var t = mc;
                var g = mc.GetInstances();
                // iterate through services until IMSAgent is found.
                foreach (ManagementObject mo in mc.GetInstances())
                {
                  if (mo.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString() == "String")
                    {
                        // get path name.
                        PropertyData pd = mo.Properties["PathName"];
                        ret = String.Concat(pd.Value.ToString(), ".config");    

                        // break.
                        break;
                    }}
```

This code throws this error at `mc.GetInstances()`

```
Access denied 
  at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
  at System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator.MoveNext()
  at **.GetIMSAgentConfigFilePath()
  at **.GetSettings(SqlConnection cn)
  at **.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

I have been Googling about different things like WMI permissions error,DCOMCON permissions error. I have tried many things like giving "Everyone" access permissions and Launch and activation permissions but this does not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices();

foreach (var service in services)
{
    string imagePath = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.GetValue(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\" + service.ServiceName + "\ImagePath");
    Console.WriteLine("service " + service.ServiceName + " = " + imagePath);
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but I am trying to find the path associated with that service, I will try to add the code that is inside the for each

Comment: Thanks for your help, but now I get a new error that seems like it could be related to my original problem:
    `Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer '.'. This operation might require other privileges.
     at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetDataBaseHandleWithAccess(String machineName, Int32 serviceControlManaqerAccess)
     at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetDataBaseHandleWithEnumerateAccess(String machineName)

Comment: @SketchyTurtle, are you try to read the services from another machine on the LAN? If so, this *will* indeed require high privileges. You might also need elevated privileges even for the local machine.

Comment: yes I am testing on a local machine, but it will eventually have to communicate on the same LAN. Are the privileges you are talking about just for the AppPool running the app?

Comment: @SketchyTurtle, "you are talking about just for the AppPool running the app" : yes. The AppPool needs to have the proper privileges. ServiceController is a sensitive api, hence the need for enhanced privileges. Alternatively, you can create a separate service that runs in the LOCAL SERVICE context and that will have the appropriate privileges. You would then need to communicate from the AppPool with this service.

Comment: Here is where it gets interesting. I tried running the code on 2 windows 10 machine. For one machine the code works and for the other I get that error mentioned earlier. I have compared WMI permissions and DCOM permissions and everything looks the same. Do have any idea what might cause the different behavior?